# Lua's package path in nginx

Tags: nginx, lua

I am now programming in Lua with nginx. I write my Lua file and place it in a directory in `/usr/local/nginx/lua`. Then in `nginx.conf` I write a location, such as

```
location /lua {
    lua_need_request_body on;
    content_by_lua_file lua/test.lua;
}
```

When I access this location through Nginx, the Lua script will be executed.

In a Lua file, one usually can include your own Lua module, and indicate the search path

```
common_path = '../include/?.lua;'
package.path = common_path .. package.path
```

In common Lua programming, a relative path is relative to my Lua file.

But with nginx, the relative paths are relative to the directory where I start Nginx.

Like, I am in `/usr/local/nginx` and execute `sbin/nginx`, then in Lua `package.path` will be the `/usr/local/include`.

If I am in `/usr/local/nginx/sbin` and execute `./nginx`, then in Lua `package.path` will be `/usr/local/nginx/include`.

I think the directory I start the nginx server should not been limited,
but I don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: Are you using HttpLuaModule ? If so, Maybe you need to set lua_package_path and/or lua_package_cpath [see doc](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#lua_package_path)

Comment: yeah, i have seen the api, but the path and cpath is relate with the '/', i doubt whether there are other methods which can make the path relate whith the nginx directory

Answer (score 22):

You want to modify the Lua `package.path` to search in the directory where you have your source code. For you, that's `lua/`.

You do this with the [`lua_package_path`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#lua_package_path) directive, in the http block (the docs say you can put it in the top level, but when I tried that it didn't work).

So for you:

```
http {
    #the scripts in lua/ need to refer to each other
    #but the server runs in lua/..

    lua_package_path "./lua/?.lua;;";

    ...
}
```

Now your lua scripts can find each other even though the server runs one directory up.

Comment: Of note, the `;;` appends the default package.path, and is not a typo.

Comment: this is the best use. Read this article also https://medium.com/@fabricebaumann/how-we-reduced-the-cpu-usage-of-our-lua-code-cc30d001a328

Answer (score 4):

You can use $prefix now.

For example

```
http{
    lua_package_path "$prefix/lua/?.lua;;";
}
```

And start your nginx like this

```
nginx -p /opt -c /etc/nginx.conf
```

Then the search path will be

```
/opt/lua
```